# Docker basics, how to keep installed packages and edited files?

Tags: docker

Do I understand Docker correctly?

1. `docker run -it --rm --name verdaccio -p 4873:4873 -d verdaccio/verdaccio`

gets verdaccio if it does not exist yet on my server and runs it on a specific port. -d detaches it so I can leave the terminal and keep it running right?

2. `docker exec -it --user root verdaccio /bin/sh`

lets me ssh into the running container. However whatever apk package that I add would be lost if I `rm` the container then run the image again, as well as any edited file. So what's the use of this? Can I keep the changes in the image?

3. As I need to edit the config.yaml that is present in `/verdaccio/conf/config.yaml` (in the container), my only option to keep this changes is to detach the data from the running instance? Is there another way?

   ```
   V_PATH=/path/on/my/server/verdaccio; docker run -it --rm --name 
   verdaccio -p 4873:4873 \
   -v $V_PATH/conf:/verdaccio/conf \
   -v $V_PATH/storage:/verdaccio/storage \
   -v $V_PATH/plugins:/verdaccio/plugins \
   verdaccio/verdaccio
   ```

However this command would throw

```
fatal--- cannot open config file /verdaccio/conf/config.yaml: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/verdaccio/conf/config.yaml'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `docker commit` to build a new image based on the container.

A better approach however is to use a `Dockerfile` that builds an image based on `verdaccio/verdaccio` with the necessary changes in it. This makes the process easily repeatable (for example if a new version of the base image comes out).

A further option is the use of volumes as you already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. When getting an existing image like verdaccio/verdaccio from the registry (with my command on 1.), does it always come with a Dockerfile that can be edited? Or is this only possible by cloning the project and building it then Dockerizing it manually?

Comment: Well, I did not say to edit the Dockerfile. Create your own with `verdaccio/verdaccio` as base image.