# why can i not run a X11 application?

Tags: docker, containers, x11

So, as the title states, I'm a `docker` newbie.
I downloaded and installed the `archlinux/base` container which seems to work great so far. I've setup a few things, and installed some packages (including `xeyes`) and I now would like to launch `xeyes`. For that I found out the CONTAINER ID by running `docker ps` and then used that ID in my exec command which looks now like:

```
$ docker exec -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY 4cae1ff56eb1 xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

Why does it still not work though? Also, how can I stop my running instance without losing its configured state? Previously I have exited the container and all my configuration and software installations were gone when I restarted it. That was not desired. How do I handle this correctly?

Comment: This answer may help with the first problem, the container has no x server to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395350/3903479.

In order to keep packages and config you'll likely want to install the required packages in the `Dockerfile`, this answer has a little more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015087/3903479

Comment: One question to a question, please. Asking how to persist state in your container should not be in the same question as asking how to run X.

Comment: (That said, if you're doing software installations interactively in your Docker container rather than from the Dockerfile, Docker may not be the right tool for your needs).

Comment: `exec`'ing into a running container and installing software is imperative (do this, do that), keeping your instructions in a `Dockerfile` is declarative (give me this). In an imperative system, if a task is interrupted, a container dies, you need to restart from scratch cf. in a declarative system if the container dies you run a new container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the X Display you need to share the `xserver` socket (**note**: `docker` can't bind mount a `volume` during an `exec`) and set the `$DISPLAY` (example `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM archlinux:base

RUN pacman -Syyu --noconfirm xorg-xeyes

ENTRYPOINT ["xeyes"]
```

Build the `docker` image: `docker build --rm --network host -t so:57733715 .`

Run the `docker` container: `docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY so:57733715`

**Note**: in case of `No protocol specified` errors you could disable host checking with `xhost +` but there is a warning to that (`man xhost` for additional information).